# Flutter released app crashes on splash screen except if '''minifyEnabled''' and '''shrinkResources''' is set to '''false'''

Tags: android, flutter

I am just wondering if anyone can tell me why does this happen.

When I test my app in emulator it works just fine. I built the signed apk and when I installed it, the app crashes after the splash screen. I googled for some answers but found no good solutions. The only thing that worked was if I set the `minifyEnabled` and `shrinkResources` to `false` in the **build.gradle**.

I am wondering why is this happening if anyone knows the answer?

**Edit**: logcat report

```
--------- beginning of crash
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.muty.drink, PID: 24642
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.muty.drink/com.muty.drink.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.muty.drink.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.muty.drink-CTcV5MKHFkhkrxhpKXkc6g==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.muty.drink-CTcV5MKHFkhkrxhpKXkc6g==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.muty.drink-CTcV5MKHFkhkrxhpKXkc6g==/split_config.en.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.muty.drink-CTcV5MKHFkhkrxhpKXkc6g==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.muty.drink-CTcV5MKHFkhkrxhpKXkc6g==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.muty.drink-CTcV5MKHFkhkrxhpKXkc6g==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.muty.drink-CTcV5MKHFkhkrxhpKXkc6g==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.muty.drink-CTcV5MKHFkhkrxhpKXkc6g==/split_config.en.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.muty.drink-CTcV5MKHFkhkrxhpKXkc6g==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3020)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3251)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1948)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7045)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.muty.drink.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.muty.drink-CTcV5MKHFkhkrxhpKXkc6g==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.muty.drink-CTcV5MKHFkhkrxhpKXkc6g==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.muty.drink-CTcV5MKHFkhkrxhpKXkc6g==/split_config.en.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.muty.drink-CTcV5MKHFkhkrxhpKXkc6g==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.muty.drink-CTcV5MKHFkhkrxhpKXkc6g==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.muty.drink-CTcV5MKHFkhkrxhpKXkc6g==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.muty.drink-CTcV5MKHFkhkrxhpKXkc6g==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.muty.drink-CTcV5MKHFkhkrxhpKXkc6g==/split_config.en.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.muty.drink-CTcV5MKHFkhkrxhpKXkc6g==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:69)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:    at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(Unknown Source:0)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1215)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3008)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:    ... 11 more
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location (arm64) /data/app/com.muty.drink-CTcV5MKHFkhkrxhpKXkc6g==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:354)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:101)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:75)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:394)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:354)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:164)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:74)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:73)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:88)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:74)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:40)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:764)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:847)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1088)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2563)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6095)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:237)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1785)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        ... 6 more
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location (arm64) /data/app/com.muty.drink-CTcV5MKHFkhkrxhpKXkc6g==/split_config.en.apk
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:354)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:101)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:75)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:394)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:354)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:164)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:74)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:73)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:88)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:74)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:40)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:764)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:847)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1088)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2563)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6095)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:237)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1785)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        ... 6 more
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location (arm64) /data/app/com.muty.drink-CTcV5MKHFkhkrxhpKXkc6g==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:354)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:101)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:75)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:394)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:354)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:164)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:74)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:73)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:88)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:74)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:40)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:764)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:847)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1088)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2563)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6095)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:237)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1785)
08-15 00:00:38.171 24642 24642 E AndroidRuntime:        ... 6 more
```

- I don't have any `proguard-rules.pro`

Comment: You should look at the crash stack trace to see what is causing the crash.

Comment: Please share your error stacktrace from logcat and the proguard-rules.pro file.